# Check Content-type POST request PHP

Tags: php, header, content-type

How can I check if the Content-type of a POST request in PHP is either application/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded?

I've tried using `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]` and `echo get_headers('url', 1)["Content-Type"]` but neither of those work for me.

Comment: `$_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]` must work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r(getallheaders());
```

So

```
$allHeaders = getallheaders();
$contentType = $allHeaders['Content-Type'];
```

Comment: The first solution that actually works for me! Can't thank you enough!

Comment: No problem :)
Be aware that you should always distrust user input and sanitise the input. The most commonly known abuse of this is SQL-injection. But headers are also being considered user-input.

Answer (score 1):

It's working below codes. You can try it

```
$headerArray = getallheaders();
$contentType = $headerArray['Content-Type'];
(Or)
$contentType =  $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];
(Or)
$headerArray = apache_request_headers(); 
$contentType = $headerArray['Content-Type'];
```